# Rewrite Rule For Base Directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

So I'm trying to rewrite the following example. Took a look around but couldn't find the correct post that matched this scenario.

Here is a list of layout for old pages:

```
www.url.com/directory
www.url.com/directory/page1.html
www.url.com/directory/page2.php
```

I'm trying to rewrite the following way through htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /directory /newdirectory
Redirect 301 /directory/page1.html /newdirectory/page1
Redirect 301 /directory/page2.php /newdirectory/page2
```

However, the first rewrite rule is interfering with old subpages in that path. So for example, using the above rewrite rules, going to:

```
www.url.com/directory/page1.html
```

Points the user to:

```
www.url.com/newdirectory/page1.html
```

When it should be pointing user to the slug without the original filename extension:

```
www.url.com/newdirectory/page1
```

The only way around this that I've been able to manage is to leave out the www.url.com/newdirectory/page1.html rule entirely. But there are a bunch of links pointing to that base path, so I'd like to redirect that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for the time and help.

url-rewriting redirect rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the rule for the base directory after the ones for the subpages :

```
Redirect 301 /directory/page1.html /newdirectory/page1
Redirect 301 /directory/page2.php /newdirectory/page2
Redirect 301 /directory /newdirectory
```